# Adding data trigger to style trigger using Blend's interface, not through xaml code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

I need some help from WPF blend wizards out there. This is more for knowledge sake as I can already implement a datatrigger in a style through explicitly changing xaml, but I would like to know if there is a way to do this through Blend.

Lets start with some code!

```
<Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="299" Margin="24,27,24,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="832" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Source="img/SpiderLogo.png" d:IsHidden="True" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Image.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="LoadTitleScreen">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </Style.Resources>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLoginValid, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}" Value="true">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource LoadTitleScreen}"/>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
```

All is well and working here! Now after building another image and editing its style resource by:

1) right-clicking the image in "Objects and Timeline"

2) edit style

3) creating a style resource

I can create storyboards and the whole nine but cannot add an datatrigger to it through Blend's interface. I go to Assets Menu to drag a ChangePropertyAction onto the style but the entire Assets Menu is greyed out/non-functional.

```
    <Image x:Name="titleBackgroundImage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="610" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="899"  Source="img/RPVBackground.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Margin="-9,-10,-10,-50" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{DynamicResource TitleScreenBackgroundImage}">
        <Image.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="TitleScreenBackgroundImage" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="LoadTitleScreenBackground">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="{x:Null}">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="0"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.1" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="{x:Null}">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </Image.Resources>
    </Image>
```

This is what I'm stuck with, a nice storyboard created in the style resource but the inability to add a trigger to call it =(

Please help if you know how! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's just Triggers you want and the that window isn't immediately open by default you can hit;

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

...or select from the top menu `View -> Triggers Window` and manage your Triggers there.

As to why your Assets tab is grayed out, well that could be a few different reasons. Would need to know more to diagnose that one. First guess would be you're just missing SDK or something? Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the response. I can open the triggers window when editing the style, but click "+ Property" to add a property trigger does nothing. Ill check on the SDK, I am currently using 2013 so that may be a problem.